# How to model location that is common to 2 dimensions?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, datamodel, star-schema

I am creating a data model and need guidance.

I have 2 dimensions: customer, product

And 2 fact tables: sales, purchases.

Both the dimensions have Location column. Suppose user selects London then it should show all customer and products from London. So I think it makes more sense to create a new dimension called Location and make it the parent of customer and product. This however makes it a snowflake schema.

Alternatively rather than making the Location as parent of customer and product, I can amend the ETL (to have the LocationID into the fact tables) so as to make the Location dimension to directly point into the fact tables. This will make it star schema.

Is there any negative impact of choosing the later option?

Answer (score 0):

Having a separate dimension that links directly to your fact table is the “standard” way of implementing this

Comment: But the location in my case is attribute of the dimension and not the fact

Answer (score 0):

If both Customer and Product have a location, then you have a "[role playing dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/role-playing-dimension/)".  You might want to filter by Customer.Location, or you might want to filter by Product.Location.  In Power BI you need two copies of your dimension here, one related to Product and one related to Location ([see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BxaUXlx3K4)).

This would also create a snowflake schema, which is not a problem.  If you'd prefer a star schema then you would copy the location data into each dimension.

You wouldn't put location on the fact table because then you couldn't distinguish between the Customer's location and the Product's location.

Comment: If I have 2 location dims, one for the product And other for customer, and then if I have a slicer on the report, then if I select 1 location value in the slicer, then is it possible to automatically filter the other location dimension too?

Comment: No they would operate separately.

Comment: So isn't it better to place the location within both the product and category tables? Rather than have separate single or multiple locations tables?

Comment: Both approaches are common.  It depends.  Do you care about locations that have no product?  Does Location have many attributes?  Etc

Comment: When I add location as a dimension to the dimension tables (product And category) then it allows only 1 link to be active due to reason being ambiguity introduced into the fact tables if both links are allowed to be active. I'm confused why this reults in ambiguous?